# How to chain two GraphQL queries in sequence using Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphcool

I am using Apollo Client for the frontend and Graphcool for the backend. There are two queries `firstQuery` and `secondQuery` that I want them to be called in sequence when the page opens. Here is the sample code (the definition of TestPage component is not listed here):

```
export default compose(
        graphql(firstQuery, {
            name: 'firstQuery'
        }),
        graphql(secondQuery, { 
            name: 'secondQuery' ,
            options: (ownProps) => ({
                variables: {
                   var1: *getValueFromFirstQuery*
                }
            })
        })
)(withRouter(TestPage))
```

I need to get `var1` in `secondQuery` from the result of `firstQuery`. How can I do that with Apollo Client and compose? Or is there any other way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The props added by your `firstQuery` component will be available to the component below (inside) it, so you can do something like:

```
export default compose(
  graphql(firstQuery, {
    name: 'firstQuery'
  }),
  graphql(secondQuery, { 
    name: 'secondQuery',
    skip: ({ firstQuery }) => !firstQuery.data,
    options: ({firstQuery}) => ({
      variables: {
          var1: firstQuery.data.someQuery.someValue
      }
    })
  })
)(withRouter(TestPage))
```

Notice that we use `skip` to skip the second query unless we actually have data from the first query to work with.

#### Using the Query Component

If you're using the `Query` component, you can also utilize the `skip` property, although you also have the option to return something else (like `null` or a loading indicator) inside the first render props function:

```
<Query query={firstQuery}>
  {({ data: { someQuery: { someValue } = {} } = {} }) => (
    <Query
      query={secondQuery}
      variables={{var1: someValue}}
      skip={someValue === undefined}
    >
      {({ data: secondQueryData }) => (
        // your component here
      )}
</Query>
```

#### Using the useQuery Hook

You can also use `skip` with the `useQuery` hook:

```
const { data: { someQuery: { someValue } = {} } = {} } = useQuery(firstQuery)
const variables = { var1: someValue }
const skip = someValue === undefined
const { data: secondQueryData } = useQuery(secondQuery, { variables, skip })
```

#### Mutations

Unlike queries, mutations involve specifically calling a function in order to trigger the request. This function returns a Promise that will resolve with the results of the mutation. That means, when working with mutations, you can simply chain the resulting Promises:

```
const [doA] = useMutation(MUTATION_A)
const [doB] = useMutation(MUTATION_B)

// elsewhere
const { data: { someValue } } = await doA()
const { data: { someResult } } = await doB({ variables: { someValue } })
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks Daniel. It's strange that I didn't find the documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: I can't believe this is working. Couldn't find this anywhere else

Answer (score 10):

For anyone using [react apollo hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/react-hooks) the same approach works.

You can use two `useQuery` hooks and pass in the result of the first query into the `skip` `option` of the second,

example code:

```js
const AlertToolbar = ({ alertUid }: AlertToolbarProps) => {
  const authenticationToken = useSelectAuthenticationToken()

  const { data: data1 } = useQuery<DataResponse>(query, {
    skip: !authenticationToken,
    variables: {
      alertUid,
    },
    context: makeContext(authenticationToken),
  })

  const { data: data2, error: error2 } = useQuery<DataResponse2>(query2, {
    skip:
      !authenticationToken ||
      !data1 ||
      !data1.alertOverview ||
      !data1.alertOverview.deviceId,
    variables: {
      deviceId:
        data1 && data1.alertOverview ? data1.alertOverview.deviceId : null,
    },
    context: makeContext(authenticationToken),
  })

  if (error2 || !data2 || !data2.deviceById || !data2.deviceById.id) {
    return null
  }
  const { deviceById: device } = data2
  return (
    <Toolbar>
    ...
    // do some stuff here with data12
```

Comment: Thank you @Damian, your post helped me to understand this feature. In my opinion this approach works only for the 2-3 sequenced queues etc., otherwise, the `skip` arguments list will be too long, just like in the answer

Comment: This works. Regarding the chain of `||`, you can actually optimize them away with the `?.` optional chaining operator! e.g. `data1?.alertOverview?.deviceId`